# Using requests.get to get redirected url

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a super long url, and I'm trying to print its final destination. I've got:

```
import requests
url = "https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.washingtonpost.com%2Fscience%2F2020%2F04%2F29%2Fcoronavirus-detection-dogs%2F%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR00eT4EHsWC9986GUSox_7JS7IIg2wAan-tB-NteYJd8I4xckmxnfaNGEI&h=AT0cs4gTKPZlkSElC2uhoDYR98lsONooq_ZUFIK87khBmtZE_3r8j25EfioBPAdp-O8o7efRVG9uB-doy9vLT-AccZMrxnfpEiSYRmA2LTL21IU15bP_PTVw4SSibS1A_uE8bU-ROJexKgdk68VSTtE&__tn__=H-R&c[0]=AT3BNcTNFE13IJu3naJmxTRdJTWtO4O4L0_-nimmzcXpYv3N536YRpQZLg-v2FtP_Oz2DZZpBN6XQPb89JNJTsYFXlK8-1g4xdDLi1T_lfowpI5Ooh8kuLpciLiQ9t-ZmMd2CTUWaGZ_Y_JU0OEvVWfLLfjDq4VOzUtETBcvXHw2ZvQnTQ"
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
print(r.headers['Location'])
```

It should get me to https://www.washingtonpost.com/science/2020/04/29/coronavirus-detection-dogs/?fbclid=IwAR00eT4EHsWC9986GUSox_7JS7IIg2wAan-tB-NteYJd8I4xckmxnfaNGEI. But I get the same URL I put in.

(By the way, if anyone happens to know how to do this in Javascript, that would be awesome, but Google tells me that's not possible.)

Comment: The code is working fine with me, I am not getting any error! I can see the ```Location``` key in the ```headers``` dictionary

Comment: It should print "https://www.washingtonpost.com/science/2020/04/29/coronavirus-detection-dogs/?fbclid=IwAR00eT4EHsWC9986GUSox_7JS7IIg2wAan-tB-NteYJd8I4xckmxnfaNGEI"

Comment: why do you want to use ```requests``` ?

Comment: I'm trying to get to the destination link so I can save a more stable URL in a database. Totally open to doing it some other way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want to get the URL, `requests` here cant be that much of help. Instead, you can use `urllib.parse`:

```
import urllib.parse as url_parse


url = <https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https...>
news_link = url_parse.unquote(url).split("?u=")[1]

# if you wish to delete Facebook Id, you can add this too
news_link  = url_parse.unquote(url).split("?u=")[1].split("?fbclid")[0]
print(news_link)
```

Comment: Hey there — I just noticed that, when coming from two locations, this can actually yield two different addresses that both start with "washingtonpost.com" and still work. I want to be able to filter by the URL, so I want a final URL that's always the same. Is there a way to cut off the url in a place before the randomly generated letters/numbers?

Comment: @codi6 It's not really clear to me what you are trying to say here, maybe you want to give an example to clear this out to me?

Comment: Yeah, added to the original questions under "Another issue" (the examples were too long for comments)

Comment: Oh! I see what happened. I thought I included your code to get rid of the Facebook ID, but I accidentally left if out. Doi! It's working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Cool, Good Luck